# How to construct a DB DataSource using parameterized custom driver class?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In a Spring Boot app, I am connecting to a Postgres DB. For a specific requirement, I need to use a parameterized DriverClass which is a subclass of `org.postgresql.Driver`.

How can I construct the `DataSource` object using a parameterized driverClass ?

```
DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("com.apps.CustomPostgresqlDriver") // Not sure how to pass a string argument to its constructor
.build()
```

The customer driver **com.apps.CustomPostgresqlDriver** is defined like this.

```
Public class CustomPostgresqlDriver implements Driver {

   public void CustomPostgresqlDriver(String appParam){

      ....
   }
...

}
```

I don't see any option to instantiate (or let Spring instantiate) the driver with the above one-arg constructor. Example:

`new CustomPostgresqlDriver("my-app-db-param")`

Comment: Wrong approach. You pass properties to the driver via "connection properties", which are given as part of the JDBC URL.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for your reply. I added some more clarification in the qts. Do you have any ex/ref of the approach you suggested?

Comment: You mean something like the [PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) showing properties that can be added to the URL?

Comment: No. If we just mention `dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("com.apps.CustomPostgresqlDriver")` then spring will instantiate an object of CustomPostgresqlDriver. right ?
I want to pass a string parameter to the constructor of the class(CustomPostgresqlDriver). I believe there should be some way to get a handle of this construction or let spring do the instantiation(which Spring does using reflection I guess) bypassing the string parameter to it.

Comment: Why does it *absolutely* have to be the constructor? Why can't it be the [`connect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#connect-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-) method of the [`Driver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html)? You know, the method that receives the JDBC URL and a `Properties` object with all the nice properties. You know, properties that you can specify right *next to* the driver class name. Stop being so focused on the constructor. That's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454).

Comment: @Andreas, Re- Why does it absolutely have to be the constructor?
 It needs to be in the constructor because that is where the custom driver creates another object(that I want to control using the string param) which retrieves some keys from the AWS secret manager.
Those keys get cached within my custom driver program and get used within the `connect()` method. I don't have much flexibility to change the driver program other than adding a parameterized constructor. Hope this clarifies why I am a bit obsessed with constructor here :). Plz let me know if you have any tips to solve this.

Comment: I really don't see why that logic cannot be deferred until the `connect()` method is called (the first time).

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataSourceBuilder to finish this task:
The first config two different ds setting in application.yml like as below:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    main: 
      driver-class-name: ${ds.driver}
      url: ${ds.url}
      username: ${ds.username}
      password: ${ds.password}
      hikari:
        maximum-pool-size: ${ds.maximum.pool.size}
        minimum-idle: ${ds.minimum.idle}
        connection-timeout: 10000
        connection-test-query: SELECT 1
    read:
      driver-class-name: ${ds.driver}
      url: ${ds.read.url}
      username: ${ds.read.username}
      password: ${ds.read.password}
      hikari:
        maximum-pool-size: ${ds.read.maximum.pool.size}
        minimum-idle: ${ds.read.minimum.idle}
        connection-timeout: 10000
        connection-test-query: SELECT 1
```

The second inject them with DataSourceBuilder as below:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.main")
    public DataSource main() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
 
 
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.read")
    public DataSource read() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case, I am not creating two data-sources. 
I need to pass a parameter to the constructor of my custom DB driver ie. com.apps.CustomPostgresqlDriver. 
updated the qts with a high-level definition of this.

Comment: If you extend DataSourceBuilder and you will realize what you want. Pls see its source code. The driver will be passed as param to your new DataSourceBuilder.

Comment: My sample just show a way on how to pass driver via yaml. If you like program, maybe it is a good way to extend DataSourceBuilder.